# python or is not placing the correct values

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to place the right location for the corresponding items, im using `or`

```
search_item = input("Input The Search Item: ")
location = input("Location:")
second_location = input("Second_Location:")

start_urls = [
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + location,
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + second_location
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + third_location,
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + fourth_location
    ]
```

`item['locations'] = second_location or location`

Not sure if im doing this correct

the `second_location` input is overiding all of the items, which is not what i want.

How it should work, for the corresponding start_url it should have the corresponding `location` or `second_location`.

**full code**

```
search_item = input("Input The Search Item: ")
location = input("Location:")
second_location = input("Second_Location:")



# city = [
#     "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Phoenix", "Philadelphia", "San Antonio", "Fort Worth", 
#     "San Diego", "Dallas", "San Jose", "Austin", "Columbus", "Indianapolis",  "Seattle", "St. Paul", "Nashville", 
#     "Louisville", "Plano"
# ]

# rancity = random.choice(city)


class YellowSpider(scrapy.Spider):


    name = "yellow"

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + location,
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + second_location
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + third_location,
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + fourth_location
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_business_names = []
        self.seen_phonenumbers = []
        self.seen_websites = []
        self.seen_emails = []



    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('div.v-card a.business-name::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.businessprofile)

        for href in response.css('div.pagination a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def businessprofile(self, response):
        for business in response.css('header#main-header'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('div.sales-info h1::text').extract()
            w = business.css('a.secondary-btn.website-link::attr(href)').extract()

            item['website'] = str(w).strip('[]')
            item['locations'] = second_location or location

            # item['second_location'] = second_location
            # elif third_location:
            #     item['location'] = third_location
            # elif fourth_location:
            #     item['location'] = fourth_location
            s = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()
            item['email'] = [item[7:] for item in s]

            item['phonenumber'] = business.css('p.phone::text').extract_first()
            for x in item['email']:
                #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
                if x not in self.seen_emails:
                    if item['email']:
                        if item['phonenumber']:
                            if item['website']:
                                self.seen_emails.append(x)
                                yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your short code and if I understand you correct it seems to work fine for me. My `start_urls` variable endded up being:
`['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=my_search_term&geo_location_terms=my_location1',
'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=my_search_term&geo_location_terms=my_location2']`

I have tried it in both python 2.7 and python 3.5 and it works for me.
Am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: the problem comes when its writing the location to the correct item

Comment: So I might not be the correct person to help, as I don't know much about scrapy, but here is what I have: in `item['locations'] = second_location or location` if "second_location" exists then item["locations"] will always take it, and will ignore "location".  Also the location you define "start_urls" and "name" seems weird, did you not mean to put it inside the _init_ function? I copied the full code and taking out scrapy and putting the "start_urls" variable in _init_ it still works for me.. Hope something I said somehow helped, otherwise sorry for wasting your time..

Comment: any possible solution to this. 

`if location:
                item['location'] = location
            if second_location:
                item['location'] = second_location`

Comment: do you see the logic  in what im trying to do.

Comment: all it does it overides all the items with `location` input

Comment: So from what I can tell it is doing what you mean it to then.. I mean your logic seems to be right for me, but because I can't see how you intend to use "start_urls" or the item that you yield then I can't really tell what might be going wrong. The `item['locations'] = second_location or location` does essentially do ` if location: item['location'] = location if second_location: item['location'] = second_location` from what I know. Again, the curious thing to me is the place that you declare `start_urls`, thats the only thing that I can see might cause an issue.